# Opening a remote file with JSON data in javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, json

I am trying to access a simple data file via javascript and finding it incredibly difficult. It will be placed on a remote server and hopefully could be accessed via http. I am new to javascript, but here goes: the best option so far I have found in JSONP, as stated here https://learn.jquery.com/ajax/working-with-jsonp/.

I have created an example datafile that I would have to process: http://murded.keeleleek.ee/test2.txt.

```
<html>

<head>
    <title>My experiment</title>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>
<script type="text/javascript">
    // Using YQL and JSONP
    $.ajax({
        url: "http://murded.keeleleek.ee/test2.txt",

        // The name of the callback parameter, as specified by the YQL service
        //jsonp: "callback",

        // Tell jQuery we're expecting JSONP
        dataType: "jsonp",

        // Tell YQL what we want and that we want JSON
        data: {
            q: "dataprev",
            format: "json"
        },

        // Work with the response
        success: function(response) {
            console.log(response); // server response
        }
    });
</script>

</html>
```

Eventually I would just like to use the JSON values as an array, and for now, just print them out to console or screen to make sure they are there. Is anyone able to help me troubleshoot this? Perhaps there is a much easier way?

Unfortunately I am new to both javascript and JSON, so there may be an easy newbie error there. The file should be on a remote server, and just read access should be enough for import. Many thanks!

Comment: The file whose content you are returning does not contain JSONP. You should read https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSONP to get more familiar with it.

Comment: Thanks, I will look into the way to encode it properly. It is not crucial that the end result use JSONP though, I just need to get the data from a file on another server to use in some way (that would not involve the user selecting the file). Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

A simple option is using $.getJson

```
$.getJSON(
        "http://murded.keeleleek.ee/test2.txt",               
           data: {
        q: "dataprev",
        format: "json"
    },
function( response ) {
        console.log( response ); // server response
    }
        )
```

Comment: Thanks, it looks clean, but it tells me of a missing ) after argument list on the line of data: { - which i personally don't see... any idea what could be wrong? The file context is exactly the same as above.

Comment: try again, there was an extra comma

Comment: That won't work, the URL contains plain text, not JSON.

Answer (score 0):

If your code, you said:

```
// Tell jQuery we're expecting JSONP
```

But your URL does not contain JSONP. It contains plain text.

In order to process it as JSONP you must format it as [JSONP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSONP).

That means:

- A core of JSON (See http://json.org/ for examples)
- Wrapped with a JavaScript function call: `foo(YOUR_JSON);`
- Served with an `application/javascript` content type (so you should use a `.js` file extension if you are serving up a static file)

If you are using a static file, then you are forced to hard code the callback name (`foo` in the example above). You need to tell jQuery what that callback name is instead of letting it generate one dynamically:

```
jsonp: "foo"
```

---

NB: JSONP is a hack to work around cross domain issues. It imposes quite a few limits compared to using XMLHttpRequest, including restrictions on what you can do to handle errors. There is now good support for [CORS](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Access_control_CORS) in browsers, so JSONP isn't needed any more. If you aren't making requests across origins then you don't event need that.

---